# 16-bit floating point division (half-precision)?

Tags: floating-point, logic, half-precision-float

how can I divide a 16-bit float point number by a 16-bit float point number (half-precision)?

I did the sign with XOR gate, the exponent with 5bit subtractor, but couldn't do the mantissa.
how can I do the normalizing and rounding?
[logisim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhH5y.png)

Comment: So far, you have done about 2% of the logic and ask for the remaining 98%.  Perhasp try more,  Consider how you [divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), now try it in base 2.

Comment: Do you want to implement this with only logic gates? Did you manage to implement integer division already (e.g., using shifting and conditional subtracting)?

Comment: I added a picture of my  logisim circuit.